# django-picklefield not deserializing custon class object

Tags: python, django, pickle

I have a model defined with a field using django-picklefield. Everything was working fine till I refactored our codebase for organizational reasons, but now when I load that model from the db I get back a unicode object instead of the unpickled object. Because the class definition moved pickle cannot find the module it needs to import, I traced the error back to [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/525faaeffc557899b83463f3b1b74d2f39cc7e13/Lib/pickle.py#L1384) where pickle tries to import a module that no longer exists.

Is there a way I can resolve this import error by pointing pickle to the correct module or somehow fake the existence of that class definition in the module pickle is looking in with other imports or by creating a class of the same name that inherits from the original class that lives elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by recreating the old file I had deleted and had it contain only a single line that imports the class that pickle was looking for.